# Cannt enable developer mode chrome selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

im trying to enable developer mode but it does not work. what am i wrong at? (chrome can open but developer mode is still not enabled)

```
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(f"--load-extension=" + ",".join([
        str(pathlib.Path("./capcha2").absolute()),
        str(pathlib.Path("./metamask").absolute())
    ]))
    prefs = {
        "extensions.ui.developer_mode": True,
        }
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs )
    options.add_argument('--no-first-run --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic')
    driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=options, user_data_dir=path_profile_chrome, )
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("--force-dev-mode-highlighting") 
options.add_argument("--system-developer-mode")
```

Comment: i tried but it not work